# Make the div with expand to the width of containing spans

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

How can I make a `div` container expand its width to contain all its child `span`s in one row?

Please see the example fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xZ77z/4/).

I would like the div to have all the buttons inside it in one row.

**UPDATE**
The table from the example can not be removed. Moreover if I had a `table` instead of the `div` then the first `table` would expand. Now I have the `div` but that's not expanding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am going to post this as another answer, as it is not really related to my first answer.

You can wrap your spans with another span that forces no line breaks:

```
<span style="white-space:nowrap">...</span>
```

This will make your div (and table) expand to contain the buttons.

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/JhDwt/

Comment: Thanks, that is really what I need. However I have another problem in my special case, but I will create a different question for that.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `div` that is constraining the `span`s to be on different rows, it is the table width:

`<table width="300">`

If you change the width to 600, for instance, all buttons will end up on the same row.

**Edit:** See my other answer for a method that does what you want.

Comment: But I need to table to have fixed width. And if I set the div width to more than 300 then it exapands, so I think it is not the main problem... is it?

Comment: You are saying that you need the table to be 300 wide, but you want the content in the table to be wider than the table?  Yes, you can force the div to be wider, but the div will be constrained to the width of the `td` unless you force it to be wider, which kind of breaks your layout, doesn't it?

Comment: What are you trying to ultimately accomplish with the table and the div?  Why do you need the table?

Answer (score 0):

It may be better to remove the table -- depending on your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/simply_simpy/nxD4G/3/

Comment: I can not remove the table. I would have to change the structure on every page of the application.

Comment: @Atticus You say that as if it would be a bad idea.